# spark-submit spring-boot app

Tags: apache-spark, spring-boot

I have a problem with submiting spring-boot application into apache-spark (standalone cluster) with spark-submit script. 
The application expose RESTful services to do some computation on spark but when I run

```
./spark-submit  --master spark://node01:7077,node02:17077 --jars spark.jar  spark.jar
```

on my master node I get following error:

```
*org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.5.RELEASE]
```

I read post on stackoverflow that some other people heave problem with login when they want to submit spring application to apache spark but I have a problem with cointainer. Are there any tutorials to writing spring-boot application to submit on spark?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it seems you need to shade your dependencies and create a uber jar. And you don't need to specify the spark.jar again in the --jars option.